# Jade nested array

Tags: pug

I'm passing an object that looks as follows:

```
res.render('lakes/index',
  {
      var1: 'some value',
      regions:
        [
          {name: 'New York', lakes: ['Lake 1', 'Lake 2']},
          {name: 'New Jursey', lakes: ['Lake 3', 'Lake 4']}
        ]
  }
);
```

The below jade template seems to have a problem with this each loop - each region in #{region.lakes}.

```
block body
      div.page-header
        h1 Lakes #{var1}
      p Some info on lakes
          - each region in regions
              p The lakes of #{region.name} ... #{region.lakes}
                    - each region in #{region.lakes}
                        p xxx
```

How does one loop the lakes in the above object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using different variables for each loop and removing the `#{}` around the expression:

```
block body
  div.page-header
    h1 Lakes #{var1}
  p Some info on lakes
    - each region in regions
      p The lakes of #{region.name} ... #{region.lakes}
        - each lake in region.lakes
            p xxx
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd tried that but Id didn't realize that the loop was still named region :)